# Dell Latitude 5501 front LED flashing white-amber

Tags: dell-latitude, led, status

I have a Dell Latitude 5501 and since today the front LED started flashing white-amber (1,1). When checking the docs, I find [this site from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/nl/nl/nlbsdt1/latitude-15-5501-laptop/latitiude_5501_sm/system-diagnostic-lights?guid=guid-f7e24b39-9988-47a8-8c7b-4f85ba0cf5dd&lang=en-us), but the pattern 1,1 is not described.

Connecting or disconnecting the power supply has no effect.

The laptop works perfectly fine.

Has anyone has this as well, or knows where to find extra docs on this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it thinks the battery is not a Dell battery.

Luckily I still have guarantee.